# Angular Highcharts dynamic import produces no additional chunk

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

Im trying to lazy load Highcharts library with dynamic import in Angular CLI project. In another cases, it's working perfectly fine and creates separate chunk. But in this scenario, while library is still included in main chunk. No additional chunk is created. Any idea what's wrong?

**Basic code example (working, but no additional js chunk):**

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "highcharts" */ 'highcharts/').then(
    (module) => {
        console.log(module.default):
    }
)
```

**tc config**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ],
        "paths": {
            "@app/*": [
                "src/app/*"
            ],
            "@environments/*": [
                "src/environments/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
    }
}
```

**ng version**

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.2
Node: 14.17.6
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 12.2.2
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.2
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.2
@schematics/angular             12.2.2
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

Comment: Could you please tell me if your chart works? Do you get any errors/warnings? I also don't understand this sentence 'But in this scenario, while library is still included in main chunk. No additional chunk is created. Any idea what's wrong?' could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, chart works ok. No errors or warnings. But lazy loading and chunk splitting doesn’t work as expected. I mean webpack dynamic import - https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports In other libraries or my own code this ends up with separate js chunk. It allows to lazy load large libraries only when really needed.

Comment: From what I have it's hard to tell what might the issue be. Will you be able to create a live demo with your code that I could debug it properly?

Comment: I found the issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/163#issue-497372364 So to dynamic import we need to use custom build library without hardcoded imports inside (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/278#issuecomment-810174207).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/163#issue-497372364):  So to dynamic import we need to use custom build library without hardcoded imports inside ([solution here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/278#issuecomment-810174207)).